# Getting random points on a mesh region

Tags: random, mesh, polygons

So I have a region defined by a `MeshRegion`,like

```
MeshRegion[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 1/2}, {2, -1/2}}, {Line[{1, 2}], Line[{2, 3}], Line[{3, 4}], Line[{4, 1}]}]
```

Which I would like to pick some random points on its border, like `{0.5,0.5}` and `{1,-0.25}`. Converting to `Graphics` and `Rasterize`, then picking random points is a way, but it would cause serious slowing down as most of the space is used to store the non-boundary points, not to mention the decreased accuracy. So is there a way to get the random points directly from the `MeshRegion`? The accuracy should be changeable.

Comment: why not `RandomPoint[mr,10]`  where `mr = MeshRegion[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 1/2}, {2, -1/2}}, {Line[{1, 2}], Line[{2, 3}], Line[{3, 4}], Line[{4, 1}]}]
`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
mr = MeshRegion[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 1/2}, {2, -1/2}}, {Line[{1, 2}], 
       Line[{2, 3}], Line[{3, 4}], Line[{4, 1}]}];
rp = RandomPoint[mr, 50];
Show[mr, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point @ rp}]
```

[image]

See the section [RandomPoint >> Scope](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomPoint.html) for examples of various forms the first argument of `RandomPoint` can take:

[image]